# SYBASE: how to capture error on a exceute

Tags: sybase

I have a query that has multiple dynamic statements, each table takes creations. construct the sentence so dynamic but not how to capture an error if it can not create the table.

```
SELECT @SQL_CREATE = 'SELECT * INTO ' || @BD || 
'PAT_CDF_CONCEPTOS_SERVICIO_ACC' || FECHA_NUMBER || 
' FROM '|| @BD || 'PAT_CDF_CONCEPTOS_SERVICIO; COMMIT;';

execute (@SQL_CREATE);
```

Comment: Sybase was a company not a database.  Please specify which Sybase DB product you are referring to (Sybase ASE, SQL Anywhere, Sybase IQ, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASE you can use syntax bellow:

```
execute (@SQL_CREATE);

IF @@error = 0
begin
    print 'Table created'
end
else
begin
    print 'Error'
end
```